# Cannot create TCHMessageOptions object with Twilio Conversations Client SDK

Tags: objective-c, xcode, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-conversations

I'm using the Twilio Conversations Client SDK in an iOS app. It works fine, but I'm getting a crash when I try and create a new `TCHMessageOptions` object to send a message.

```
TCHMessageOptions *message = [[TCHMessageOptions alloc] withBody:value];
```

The crash is happening inside this method. Xcode just shows me the assembly in the debugger.

I've also tried creating a `TCHMessageOptions` with the other instance methods, but they crash too.

```
#0  0x00000001a05b32e4 in std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::operator=(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) ()
#1  0x0000000102f90f34 in rtd::TMessageOptions::withBody(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) [inlined] at /Users/distiller/rtd-sdk-monorepo/cpp/chat-lib/Interface/Chat/ITMOptions.h:102
#2  0x0000000102f90f28 in -[TCHMessageOptions withBody:] at /Users/distiller/rtd-sdk-monorepo/sdk/ios/convo/Sources/TCHMessageOptions.mm:72
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the crash log.

Comment: I don't have access to the source code. The crash is happening inside the framework.

Comment: I see - in that case I would contact the framework developer if you haven't done so already.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio Developer is here.

The best way to solve your issue is to file a [support ticket](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/requests/new).
In general, version of the SDK you are using is required to answer your question.

While setting body for a message options, make sure that body is available (not `nil`) and it has type of a `NSString`.